# How can I copy Elasticsearch data to a new server?

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch on a new server. I have an index called metrics where custom metrics from my apps get pushed. What I want to do is add the metrics from my old server to this index.

I've tried to use elasticdump on the old server like so:
`elasticdump --input=http://oldserver:9200/metrics --output=metrics_dump.json --type=data` but after around 1,000,000 entries being added to the file, I get an error (metrics has around 10,000,000 entries on the old server).
So I thought to use scroll and save the entries in batches:
`elasticdump --input=http://oldserver:9200/metrics --output=metrics_dump_1.json --type=data --searchBody='{ "sort": ["_doc"], "query": { "match_all": {} }, "size": 100000 }`
but this doesn't work. Entries keep getting written to the file after the 100,000 mark. Also, on inspecting the first lines in the output file, I don't see a scroll_id, so I suspect the searchBody argument is ignored.

Any (other) way I can move this data? I need to not lose any newer entries from the new server metrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options. If you can stop elasticsearch in the old server just stop it and copy the data directory. That will copy everything.

If not, then you can use [snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html). Make a snapshot and restore the data in the new server. You can specify which indices are to be backed up and/or restored. Example for making a snapshot :

```json
    PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_2?wait_for_completion=true
    {
      "indices": "index_1,index_2",
      "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": false,
      "metadata": {
        "taken_by": "kimchy",
        "taken_because": "backup before upgrading"
      }
    }
```

Example for restoring a snapshot (after copying the snapshot folder to the new server) :

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
```

Unless you have configured any snapshots folders already you will have to reconfigure and restart elasticsearch.

A third option would be to copy the data with [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) using a remote server.

```json
    POST _reindex
    {
      "source": {
        "remote": {
          "host": "http://otherhost:9200",
          "username": "user",
          "password": "pass"
        },
        "index": "source",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "test": "data"
          }
        }
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "dest"
      }
    }
```

This third option should work without restarting elasticsearch.

Comment: Copying the data directory is not recommended and should be avoided, snapshot or reindex are the correct ways to do that, logstash can also be used with an elasticsearch input (old server) and an elasticsearch output (new server)

Comment: I ended up writing a small console app to import the metrics from the old server to the new. Both snapshot and reindex required changes be made to elasticsearch.yml and a subsequent restart, which I wanted to avoid for the production service.

Comment: The 3rd Option worked the best for me to copy and index from Elastic Cloud to a on-premise Dev Environment

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer posted by @julodnik, one of the easiest ways to copy data is to make your `new` ES cluster `join` the old/existing ES cluster. This can be done by configuring properties in `elasticsearch.yml` in the new cluster to be similar to the existing one especially the properties master nodes (`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`)and cluster name ('cluster.name`). That way the new cluster will join the existing cluster and data will be evenly balanced. You can then exclude the old cluster using

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "IP_of_old_cluster"
  }
}
```

before shutting it down.

Another option is to set up logstash to read index `metrics` and write to ES. You need to configure logstash.conf for it such that it reads entire `metrics` index. Something like

```
## SOURCE
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://your_old_es_host:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "foopass"
    index => "metrics"
    scroll => "5m"
    size => 5000
    docinfo_fields => [ "_id" ]
    query => '{"query":
               {"match_all": {}
                }}'
  }
}

## TARGET
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://your_new_es_host:9200"]
    index => "metrics-new"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "foopass"
  }
}
```